# Shell Exec on webserver

Tags: php, shell, powershell

I have a wesbite that uses a shell exec to render a video file. It executes the following php code:

```
shell_exec('powershell -File C:\Render\templater.ps1 -v "CC 2017" -m);
shell_exec('powershell -File C:\Render1\templater.ps1 -v "CC 2017" -m);
```

Both shell execs have thier own files in their folders. Individually, they  execute fine, but when they are run at the same time the 2nd users command fails. Is there any work around that would allow the server to run multiple shell exec calls or will I have to implement a queue manager like gearrman?

Templater.ps1 code is below:

```
Param (
    [string]$v = " ",
    [switch]$ui = $false,
    [switch]$m  = $false,
    [switch]$h  = $false
)

$usage = @'
    Desc:   
        Launches Templater for Adobe After Effects
        from the command line.  A supported version of
        After Effects is required to be installed on this 
        machine for this launcher to work properly.
    Usage:
        .\templater.ps1 -v 'ae_version_string' [-ui] [-m]
    Options:
        -h
        Shows this documentation
        -v | --version 'ae_version_string'
        The version of AE you want to use with Templater, 
        where 'version_string' can be any ofthe following: 
        'CC 2017' 'CC 2015.3' 'CC 2015' 'CC 2014' 'CC' 'CS6' 'CS5.5' 'CS5'
        -ui 
        If specified, Adobe After Effects will launch with its
        graphical user interface
        -m
        If included, this causes AE to launch as a new, seperate,
        process.  This is useful if you want to simultaneously
        execute two or more versioning jobs with Templater.
    Examples:
        Launch without AE user interface

          > .\templater.ps1 -v 'CC 2015'
          > .\templater.ps1 -v 'CS5'


        Launch with AE user interface

          > .\templater.ps1 -v 'CC 2015' -ui
          > .\templater.ps1 -v 'CS5' -ui
        Launch new instance of AE without its user interface
          > .\templater.ps1 -v 'CC 2015' -m
'@


if ([string]::IsNullorWhitespace($v) -or $h -eq $true) {
    $usage
exit
}

if ($v -ne "CC 2017" -and $v -ne "CC 2015.3" -and $v -ne "CC 2015" -and $v -ne "CC 2014" -and $v -ne "CC" -and $v -ne "CS6" -and $v -ne "CS5.5" -and $v -ne "CS5") {
"
`t`tTemplater CLI Error: Please specify a valid string for the version of After Effects you want to launch. Use -h for more information.
"
exit
}

if ($ui -eq $false) {
    $ui_switch = "-noui"
} else {
    $ui_switch = " "
}

if ($m -eq $false) {
    $m_switch = " "
} else {
    $m_switch = "-m"
}

# Read templater-options.json file if it exists
if (Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\templater-options.json"){

    $opts = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\templater-options.json"
    $conf = $opts -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json

    $log_path   = $conf.log_location
    $aep_file   = $conf.aep
    $data_src   = $conf.data_source
    $output_dir = $conf.output_location
    $output_mod = $conf.output_module
    $ftg_dir    = $conf.source_footage
    $row_start  = $conf.row_start
    $row_end    = $conf.row_end
    $pfx        = $conf.output_prefix

} else {

    echo "`nTemplater CLI configuration file 'templater-options.json' file not found.`nSee you next time :)"
    exit

}

$app_dir="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects $v\Support Files"
$panels="$app_dir\Scripts\ScriptUI Panels"
$templater_filename="Templater 2.jsxbin"
$templater_panel="$panels\$templater_filename"

"`t`t* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
`t`t*                                                               *
`t`t*    Templater CLI Launcher for Microsoft Windows Powershell    *
`t`t*                                                               *
`t`t* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
`t`tAdobe After Effects executable
`t`t`t$app_dir\afterfx.exe
`t`tCLI configuration file =>
`t`t`t$PSScriptRoot\templater-options.json
`t`tUsing following configuration =>
`t`t`tLog Dir         : $log_path
`t`t`tAE Project      : $aep_file
`t`t`tVersioning Data : $data_src
`t`t`tFootage Dir     : $ftg_dir
`t`t`tOutput Dir      : $output_dir
`t`t`tOutput Module   : $output_mod
`t`t`tOutput Prefix   : $pfx
`t`t`tTask Range      : $row_start through $row_end
`t`tInitializing Project Directory =>
`t`t`tCopying `"$app_dir\$templater_filename`" to `"$PSScriptRoot\$templater_filename`""
Copy-Item -Force $templater_panel "$PSScriptRoot\$templater_filename"

$cmd = "$app_dir\afterfx.exe"
$cmd_args = "$ui_switch $m_switch -r  $PSScriptRoot\$templater_filename"

"
`t`tInvoking Adobe After Effects $v =>
`t`t`t$cmd $ui_switch $m_switch -r `"$PSScriptRoot\$templater_filename`"
"

$scriptblock = {

    param($cmd, $cmd_args)

    $process = New-Object system.Diagnostics.Process

    $si = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $si.FileName = $cmd
    $si.Arguments = $cmd_args
    $si.UseShellExecute = $false
    $si.RedirectStandardOutput = $true

    $process.StartInfo = $si
    $process.Start() | Out-Null

    do {
        Write-Host `t`t`t $process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
    } until ($process.HasExited)

}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $cmd, $cmd_args

if ([string]::IsNullorWhitespace($log_path)) {
    $log_path = $env:TEMP
}

"
`t`tTemplater messages and errors logged to =>
`t`t`t$log_path\templater.log
`t`t`t$log_path\templater.err
`t`tLast logged message =>
"
if (Test-Path "$log_path\templater.log"){
    Get-Content "$log_path\templater.log" | Select-Object -last 1
} else {
    "`t`t`t[No log messages]"
}
"
`t`tLast reported error =>
"
if (Test-Path "$log_path\templater.err"){
    Get-Content "$log_path\templater.err" | Select-Object -last 1
} else {
    "`t`t`t[No error messages]"
    "0"
```

Comment: Are you accidentally letting multiple users run the command using the same input or output files?  That will go horribly wrong.  You need to render to different files, and probably from different inputs.

Comment: Nah so when I am testing I am using these 2 command to test at the same time:

shell_exec('powershell -File C:\Render\templater.ps1 -v "CC 2017");
shell_exec('powershell -File C:\Render2\templater.ps1 -v "CC 2017");

So they are similar commands but each one is in its own folder. So it's not that they are using the same files.

Does php allow multiple shell_exec calls (from different users) to be run providing the files they are using are different? or do all calls go to the same shell_exec?

Comment: Are you sure the .ps1 file does not use a file for both?  You probably need to edit the question to add the PS1 file for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Dave. I have added in the ps1 code. When i run the above 2 commands on the command line at the same time (in different shells) it works fine, so i don't think it is anything to do with sharing files.